# BizTalk Server Custom Pipeline Component for Removing the trailer from the .txt file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Can anybody help with a Sample Custom Receive Pipeline Component to remove the Trailer of the input .txt file. I am new to BizTalk and struggling since last week but nothing worked.It would be great if somebody helps me to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the same issues over at MSDN.

You have to learn on your own but I will give you a tip, basically, how I would approach it, first time at least.

1. Copy the message Steam while looking for CR/LF, or whatever line delimiter it is.
2. Keep track of the Position of the last CR/LF.
3. When you find the end of the Stream, either don't copy the last line or reset the Position to the last CR/LF.

Keep at it, once you get it, you'll see how simple it really is.